# iOS Container View Controller - using PerformSelector after transitionFromViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, performselector

We have a container view controller and want to be able to call "PerformSelector" on one of the "sub" view controllers in that container, right after starting a transition, i.e.

```
[self navigateSubViewControllerTo:newSubViewController];
```

... some time later, elsewhere in the stack, a selector will be performed on the top visible VC

```
[subViewController performSelector:@selector(foo)];
```

The call to transitionFromViewController happens in navigateSubViewController.Unfortunately, since transitionFromViewController happens asynchronously, we are finding that the performSelector call gets applied to the "before" sub view controller, not newSubViewController. I.e. it is happening before the transition happens.

Any thoughts on how to have performSelect not happen until the sub view controller transition happens?

Comment: `[subViewController performSelector:@selector(foo)];` is just the same as `[subViewController foo];`

Comment: True, and it still has the same bug. I've clarified the note above to indicate that the performSelector happens later, in a different system. We're using performSelector on the "top view controller", so we don't actually know what the specific view controller is.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call performSelector in the completion block of 
transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:

Comment: Unfortunately, the performSelector is happening at a different layer. We don't know we need to call it at the time we call transitionFromViewController.

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` provides a callback `beginAppearanceTransition:animated:` which is exactly for this purpose. Simply implement it in your subviewcontrollers and your good to go ;)

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite follow. How would that fix the ordering? Would I use beginAppearanceTransition instead of transitionFromViewController? Thanks.

Comment: I mean instead of implementing `foo` on your sub view controller and calling `performSelector:` after you call `navigateSubViewControllerTo:`, just override `beginAppearanceTransition:animated` in your sub view controller and move the code from `foo` to it.

Comment: `beginAppearanceTransition:animated` automatically get's called by `UIKit` on the involved vcs when you call `transitionFromViewController...`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Unfortunately, the performSelector is happening at a different layer, and doesn't always occur. We are using the performSelector as a notification, but it is going to the wrong ViewController at the moment. Interestingly, we don't see this race condition if we are using normal push/pop view controller. Somehow it blocks or queues the selector in that case.